# Plot occurrences over time in R or MATLAB from a dataset of the date of each occurrence

Tags: r, matlab, plot

I have a dataset where one column is a date of occurrence for each entry. I'd like to plot the occurrences of various subsets of this dataset over time. (See the sample data if this description is unclear.)

This differs from the case where one has a column of time periods, such as years, and another of number of occurrences within that year. I need a way to group the dates, in the way occurrences in a range are grouped into bins to make a histogram, so that I can obtain frequency over a corresponding time interval that I can plot.

I'm on the verge of writing python code to calculate these frequencies for arbitrary intervals semi-manually, but that would add a step to the process that I would have to repeat for each subset of the dataset.

Is there a package or an inbuilt function in R or MATLAB that does this already? If so, how would I go about using it to do this?

---

Below is some sample data, if my earlier description was unclear:

```
Category,Date  
V,07/01/1993
Y,05/18/2004
X,12/20/2000
X,02/19/2002
X,02/19/2002
X,02/19/2002
V,04/14/2002
V,12/20/2000
V,12/20/2000
V,01/08/2002
Y,07/18/2006
V,12/20/2000
V,12/20/2000
Y,04/20/2006
X,11/12/2009
X,04/03/2014
```

My desire is to plot number of occurrences of category V over time, such that it can be compared to Y over time and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ggplot2 specifying `fill=Category`using `geom_density` with an `alpha` value:`

```
library(ggplot2)

DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")    
ggplot(DF, aes(Date, fill = Category)) + 
      geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
      scale_x_date()
```

[image: screenshot]

or use histograms:

```
ggplot(DF, aes(Date, fill = Category)) + 
      geom_histogram() +
      scale_x_date()
```

[image: screenshot]

**Note:** This was used for `DF`:

```
Lines <- "Category,Date  
V,07/01/1993
Y,05/18/2004
X,12/20/2000
X,02/19/2002
X,02/19/2002
X,02/19/2002
V,04/14/2002
V,12/20/2000
V,12/20/2000
V,01/08/2002
Y,07/18/2006
V,12/20/2000
V,12/20/2000
Y,04/20/2006
X,11/12/2009
X,04/03/2014"
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines)
```

Comment: I was fiddling around with ggplot, but kept throwing myself errors, being quite inexperienced with R. This worked perfectly! Thank you so much!